# Calculate limit of Floor $\Rightarrow (n^2+n+1)*[\frac {2019}{n^2+n+1}]$

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I can't figure out how to solve it.

The sequence is :
$(n^2+n+1)*[\frac {2019}{n^2+n+1}]$

I tried using the formula $x-1\lt [x] \le x$ and find the limit using the squeeze theorem.

so I get $\frac {2019}{n^2+n+1} -1 \lt [\frac {2019}{n^2+n+1}] \le \frac {2019}{n^2+n+1}$ , multyipling each side by ($n^2+n+1$).

$2019-(n^2+n+1) \lt (n^2+n+1)[\frac {2019}{n^2+n+1}] \le 2019$.

well , $\lim_{n\to \infty} (2019-(n^2+n+1)) = -\infty $.

$\lim_{n\to \infty} 2019 = 2019$

No common limit between them , so I can't use the squeeze theorem.

Thank you

Comment: When $n^2+n+1>2019$, $[\frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}]=0$, so the limit is $0$.

Comment: @DerekLuna No, one of the multipler reaches $0$ for finite number $n$.

Comment: @Ivan Looking at the formula, you are talking about the floor, not the ceiling. As soon as $\frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}<1$, the floor is exactly zero. In fact your sequence has zero terms for $n\ge 45$.

Comment: Your function $[x]$ is called *floor*, not ceiling.

Comment: oops I see now , I though about floor and wrote ceiling (*facepalm*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say ceiling, but you use the definition of floor. Ok, so:

***if you meant floor***

The floor of $[\frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}]=0$ is identically zero for $n$ big enough (say $n>2019$). So your sequence looks like $a_1, \dots, a_{2019}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots$

In particular, then, its limit for $n \to \infty$ is $0$.

***if you meant ceiling***

Here things are more interesting. Note that $n \leq [n]$. Now you have an indeterminate form because $[\frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}] =1$ but $[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}] = [0] = 0$.

What you can do is consider the following:

$$ (n^2+n+1) \frac{2019}{n^2+n+1} \leq (n^2+n+1) \left[\frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}\right]$$

which tells you that the limit cannot be zero, as the sequence is uniformly bigger than $2019$.

Now note that for big enough $n$ (just as before, take $n>2019$),
$$(n^2+n+1) \left[\frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}\right] = n^2+n+1$$

since the quantity inside the brackets is nonzero, but certainly smaller than $1$, so its ceiling is $1$. In particular then your sequence gets arbitrarily big: for any number $M>0$, there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ you have that $a_n > M$, so the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: okay , but then we have inf * 0.. ($n^2+n+1$) $\rightarrow \infty$ and the fraction $\rightarrow 0$

Comment: No! The ceiling of the fraction is identically equal to $1$ for $n$ big enough (ceiling is not a continuous function, so $\lim [a_n]$ is not necessarily equal to $[ \lim a_n]$ for a sequence $a_n$ )

Comment: it's floor , not ceiling.

Comment: Oh, okay, the floor case. Well, the sequence is identically zero after a certain $n$, so just apply the definition of a limit and you'll get that it's zero (also: floor is also not a continuous function)

Comment: so I can't really find it using Limit arithmetic because I get 0*$\infty$. I can prove it by showing thats the limit is 0 after a certain n huh ?

Comment: You can't use limit arithmetic ("algebra of limits") because the conditions that would enable you to do so are not satisfied by this sequence. What you can do is use the definition of a limit (that one always works).

Answer (score -1):

Answer is Zero.
start with inside of brackets.as $n$ goes to infinity $\frac{2019}{n^2+n+1}$ goes to zero and is positive so its floor is absolute zero and we know that multiply of each number by absolute zero is zero.

Comment: But ($n^2+n+1$) is not bounded , so we can't multiply between the limits by Limit arithmetic